# iMacro Read File Names

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have to know if there is a way for iMacros with javascript to read in file names from my computer?

I already know that iMacros can upload a file from the file system to a website, below is an example from using the Record function with firefox and twitter.

```
URL GOTO=https://twitter.com/i/notifications
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:global-new-tweet-button
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ACTION://upload.twitter.com/i/tweet/create_with_media.iframe     ATTR=NAME:media_empty CONTENT=/home/michael/files/file1.jpg
```

Assuming in my folder /home/michael/tatts/ there is a `file1` `file2` and `file3`. 
Is there a way to create a `var files[] = {...}` where the ... is a list of all the file names in the folder.

I would like to use the above code to post specific images to twitter.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps here is the simplest way to get an array of the files from 'myFolder':

```
SET myFolder D:/Temp/img/
URL GOTO=file:///{{myFolder}}
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TBODY ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SET files EVAL("var f = []; var a = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/.+/g); for (i in a) {if (i % 4 == 0) f.push(a[i]);} JSON.stringify(f);")
PROMPT {{files}}
```

FYI. You can also find alternative solutions by searching on 'stackoverflow'.

Comment: Would you be able to comment on what the JS in the eval is doing?

Comment: The JS is doing some magic in the `EVAL` command :) ...And how do I know whether this code is helpful to you?